Is it possible to do an INNER JOIN between 2 containers on the query level?
This is the current layout of our data: ContainerA contains all the data saved in our webform. In ContainerA is a header field that, when crossed check against another container, helps us determine which is the active value shown in the webform in the event a write operation creates duplicate records (which there are and have yet to be deleted).
ContainerB contains the currently active header value for each of the record in ContainerA. To resolve duplicates, we do an INNER JOIN between the two containers. We are loading both containers in Power BI, creating 2 datasets in the process, before we perform the INNER JOIN.
Is it possible to skip the process of loading both containers as 2 separate datasets and doing the INNER JOIN directly from the query?

It's not possible to join two containers in Cosmos DB, it allows only self joins means data within in the same container.

FYI this is a duplicate of this question

NO, Cosmos DB's JOIN functionality is limited to self-joins within the same document. It doesn't support joining across multiple containers. To achieve a similar outcome, you'll need to run separate queries against each container.

Not the place to make roadmap commitments - removed from your answer (also the question doesn't really need an answer - this is fully documented - a link, as a comment under the question, takes care of it)

Also, you should probably just mark this question as a duplicate of this one
